# How to run bower init into gulpfile?

Tags: node.js, gulp, bower

I've just used gulp-bower plugin to run bower init in my slush generator.

```
bower = require('gulp-bower');

gulp.task('bower', function() {
return bower({cmd: 'init'});
});
```

But it gives me an error: Register requires an interactive shell.

Comment: can you share what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

bower [init](http://bower.io/docs/api/#init) requires user interaction. Running this command will fail if bower is not configured to run [interactively](http://bower.io/docs/config/#interactive).
You can bypass this error by having a *.bowerrc* file which configures Bower to run interactively:

```
{
    "interactive": true
}
```

However you will still need to find a way to provide the required input to the bower init command. As far as I've seen the command does not receive any input parameters but expects the input from the user (via STDIN).
If your intent is to bootstrap a bower.json file, you may want to consider using some kind of templating mechanism instead of running bower init.